# Runtime error for VB6 with SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

We are facing some run time errors,  We re using vb 6 and sqlserver 2008, can any one helping me with the error, I have tried to find out the solution, But not getting the solution.

[image]

Comment: vb 6 is old and also sqö server 2008, switch to vb net and a newer Version, that said, you are wrong here, such problmes are discussed at Stackoverflow. but your error message says it all, some one has chnaged the row you trying to edit/update

Comment: Sounds like you need to add a Try/Catch of sorts with retry logic that refreshes your dataset first, when this kind of error occurs.